# Using watchdog to put newly created file names into variables

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I would like to use watchdog to find new files that are created in one folder. The file name will then be used in a different function. I am using this code here:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format=' %(message)s')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

This gives the output for example in the console:

```
Created file: ./test_file.h5
Modified directory: .
Modified file: ./test_file.h5
Modified directory: .
```

What I would like is only when new files are created, that the name of them be returned and I don't need it returned in the console but just rather returned in a variable so I can use it as an input for a different function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm writing answer of this, mind if I use pathlib.Path instead of path string?

Comment: I'm not sure the difference but I think it is ok. I used the code above from an example from the  watchdog documentation so changing it should be no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom handler, it can be done by inheriting `FileSystemEventHandler` and overriding event you want to use.

```py
class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, callback: Callable):
        self.callback = callback

    def on_created(self, event: Union[DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent]):
        print(f"Event type: {event.event_type}\nAt: {event.src_path}\n")

        if isinstance(event, FileCreatedEvent):
            file = pathlib.Path(event.src_path)

            print(f"Processing file {file.name}\n")

            self.callback(file)
```

Available events are:

- on_modified(self, event)
- on_deleted(self, event)
- on_closed(self, event)
- on_moved(self, event)
- on_any_event(self, event)

Each event could vary, for on_created - it would be safe to assume it's only `DirCreatedEvent` and `FileCreatedEvent`.

--

Example code

```py
import time
import pathlib
from typing import Union

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent


class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    """Custom handler for Watchdog"""

    def __init__(self):
        # List to store path
        self.path_strings = []

    # callback for File/Directory created event, called by Observer.
    def on_created(self, event: Union[DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent]):
        print(f"Event type: {event.event_type}\nAt: {event.src_path}")

        # check if it's File creation, not Directory creation
        if isinstance(event, FileCreatedEvent):
            
            # if so, do something with event.src_path - it's path of the created file.
            self.path_strings.append(event.src_path)

            print(f"Path content: \n{self.path_strings}")


def main():
    # get current path as absolute, linux-style path.
    working_path = pathlib.Path(".").absolute().as_posix()

    # create instance of observer and CustomHandler
    observer = Observer()
    handler = CustomHandler()

    # start observer, checks files recursively
    observer.schedule(handler, path=working_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example output

```py
Event type: created
At: E:/github/ProjectIncubator/single_run_scripts\test.a
Path content: 
['E:/github/ProjectIncubator/single_run_scripts\\test.a']
Event type: created
At: E:/github/ProjectIncubator/single_run_scripts\nyan.txt
Path content: 
['E:/github/ProjectIncubator/single_run_scripts\\test.a', 'E:/github/ProjectIncubator/single_run_scripts\\nyan.txt']
```

---

## Old

Full Example Code

```py
import time
import pathlib
import argparse
from typing import Union, Callable

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent


class CustomHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def __init__(self, callback: Callable):
        self.callback = callback

        # Store callback to be called on every on_created event

    def on_created(self, event: Union[DirCreatedEvent, FileCreatedEvent]):
        print(f"Event type: {event.event_type}\nAt: {event.src_path}\n")

        # check if it's File creation, not Directory creation
        if isinstance(event, FileCreatedEvent):
            file = pathlib.Path(event.src_path)

            print(f"Processing file {file.name}\n")

            # call callback
            self.callback(file)


def main():
    path: pathlib.Path = args.dir

    # list for new files
    created_files = []

    # create callback
    def callback(path_: pathlib.Path):
        print(f"Adding {path_.name} to list!")
        created_files.append(path_)

    # create instance of observer and CustomHandler
    observer = Observer()
    handler = CustomHandler(callback)

    observer.schedule(handler, path=path.absolute().as_posix(), recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    print("Observer started")

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()

    print(f"{len(created_files)} new files was created!", "\n".join(p.name for p in created_files), sep="\n")
    input("Press enter to exit!")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # get script's root
    ROOT = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent

    # parse argument - if provided given directory is used, otherwise 
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Listen for file change in directory.")

    parser.add_argument("dir", metavar="DIR", type=pathlib.Path, default=ROOT, nargs="?", help="Directory to listen for. If omitted, script path is used.")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main()
```

---

Example output (Line breaks are mess, sorry!)

```
❯ py .\watchdog_test.py X:\test
Observer started
Event type: created
At: X:/test\새 폴더

Event type: created
At: X:/test\meow.txt

Processing file meow.txt

Adding meow.txt to list!
Event type: created
At: X:/test\meow.txt

Processing file meow.txt

Adding meow.txt to list!
Event type: created
At: X:/test\meow - 복사본.txt

Processing file meow - 복사본.txt

Adding meow - 복사본.txt to list!
Event type: created
At: X:/test\meow - 복사본 (2).txt

Processing file meow - 복사본 (2).txt

Adding meow - 복사본 (2).txt to list!
Event type: created
At: X:/test\meow - 복사본 (3).txt

Processing file meow - 복사본 (3).txt

Adding meow - 복사본 (3).txt to list!
5 new files was created!
meow.txt
meow.txt
meow - 복사본.txt
meow - 복사본 (2).txt
meow - 복사본 (3).txt
Press enter to exit!
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. I just need the file name returned and that is it.

Comment: File name is in `pathlib.Path.name` with extension. I always recommend to use `pathlib.Path` for file manipulation of any kind, in case you need more processing with path later. This already demonstrated how to save file path as variable if you prefer TL;DR, all you need is editing and reducing unnecessary parts.

Comment: In short, watch what `callback` does. it *Does* get path object as variable.

Comment: Is the parser code necessary? I don't really know what that code is doing but I would like to understand it if it is necessary.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I'll strip all down and write short simple one instead - I assumed you got path parameter as parameter or if not provided use current directory. Argument Parser part is exactly for same role!

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know argument parser is for the same role. Thank you for your answer it is really insightful.